# How to parse log using telegraf for dynamic logname that changes daily?

Tags: influxdb, logparser, telegraf

Everyone, please need help.
I am using telegraf now as a log feeder for my InfluxDB database, the concept is my telegraf will read a log then send the result to InfluxDB.

```
[[inputs.logparser]]
files = ["/here/is/the/directory/logname.log"]
from_beginning = false
```

It works as expected when the log file name is logname.log. But, today i need to changes the logname system to logname.20170320.log where 20170320 is the date of log. Do you mind, how is the right configuration for:

```
files = ["/here/is/the/directory/logname.log"]
```

So it can read the daily log that the name dynamicly changed everyday like:

```
files = ["/here/is/the/directory/logname.20170320.log"]
files = ["/here/is/the/directory/logname.20170321.log"]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can write a script which daily changes the log file name to the current date.

Comment: Thanks @Luv33preet for the insight, i already implement your idea, and it works perfectly. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Luv33preet comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895738/how-to-parse-log-using-telegraf-for-dynamic-logname-that-changes-daily#comment72998784_42895738), then i make a script to change the configuration daily using sed, here is the code:

```
/bin/sed -i "s/`date +'%Y%m%d' -d '1 day ago'`/`date +'%Y%m%d'`/" /etc/telegraf/conf.d/my-config.conf
```

To change telegraf configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you just set a wildcard for your logfile?

```
[[inputs.logparser]]
  /var/log/*/*.log    -> find all .log files with a parent dir in /var/log
  from_beginning = false
```

Comment: I think it's a bad advice (even if it sounds good), because telegraf will listen to all files matching the pattern to see if any changes. So if you have 1 file a day, that's 365 listeners in a year.